# Fetching Data from excel file using Excel power query(Get Data > From File > From Folder)

Tags: excel, powerquery, dashboard, powerpivot, excel-365

I am trying to pull data to an Excel sheet (to make Power pivot) using power query. But whenever it starts fetching the data it shows this error after few seconds:

```
The operation failed because the source database does not exist, the source table does not exist, or because you do not have access to the data source.
More Details: OLE DB or ODBC error: [Expression error] The key didnt match any row in the table.
An error occurred while processing table 'data'.
The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.
```

The files are present in the specified folder, also i have full access (read/write) to the folder and the files.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Same with me. I am using Office 365 32 bit - are you? I found this article and followed its recommendations to no avail, but maybe it will work for others:https://www.sumproduct.com/blog/article/power-query-blogs/power-query-thanks-for-the-memory?l=0

Its crazy bc the preview works, I get all the info back, but then it fails when I click "Close and Load"


I turned on tracing and the details say ExceptionType: System.OutOfMemoryException

To turn on tracing: click Data/GetData/QueryOptions/Diagnositcs to check the EnableTracing checkbox.